# Change color of Angular Material component mat-list-option checkbox for checked background, frame and check mark

Tags: css, angular, sass, angular-material, angular-components

In Angular application, using of Angular Material

I've changed color for `<mat-checkbox>My Checkbox</mat-checkbox>` *checked background* and *frame* like this:

```
::ng-deep .mat-checkbox .mat-checkbox-frame {
  border-color: rgb(130, 238, 148);
}

::ng-deep .mat-checkbox-checked .mat-checkbox-background {
  background-color: rgb(251, 255, 0) !important;
}
```

but I can't find the way to do the same with  checkbox *checked background*, *frame* and *check mark*:

```
<mat-selection-list>
  <mat-list-option
    *ngFor="let dt of data"
    [value]="dt.value"
  >
    {{ dt.myValue }}
  </mat-list-option>
</mat-selection-list>
```

Using of same `::ng-deep` with `.mat-list-option .mat-list-option-frame` does not gives result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can alter `selection-list` checkboxes with a different set of rules. Here I have changed the accent color checkboxes:

```
::ng-deep {

  .mat-accent .mat-pseudo-checkbox-checked,
  .mat-accent .mat-pseudo-checkbox-indeterminate {
    background: green;
  }

  .mat-accent .mat-pseudo-checkbox.mat-pseudo-checkbox-checked,
  .mat-accent .mat-pseudo-checkbox.mat-pseudo-checkbox-indeterminate {
    border-color: blue;
  }

  .mat-accent .mat-pseudo-checkbox::after {
    color: red;
  }
}
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ubma2v?file=src%2Fapp%2Flist-selection-example.scss

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer. I've already tried this code, but it changes only background. My goal is also change frame and check mark color (I've missed to note last one in my post) please check edit

Comment: @iose936 I've updated the answer to include frame and check, hopefully that gets you closer to what you need.